# jquery .addType()

Tags: jquery, function, add-type

Is there a .addType() function for jquery? I know there's a .addClass() to add the class, but I'm appending an input element to a div using the shorthand way and was wondering if there is a .addType() to add the type to the input area i.e text, password, submit.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#newnum").click(function(){
    $("#equation").append(
      $("<input/>")
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: Why not just do `$("<input type='text' />")`?

Comment: `$("<input type='text' />")` is your only real option because some versions of IE won't allow you to change the type attribute of an input after it has been created.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could just use the shorthand

```
$('<input type="text">');
```

There is also the `attr()` which would let you do the same thing

```
$('<input>').attr('type', 'text');
```

Answer (score 6):

You can pass the type attribute like this :

```
$("<input/>").attr('type','text')
```

If you need to set more than just one attribute :

```
$('<input />', {type:'text', class:'css-class', value:"Hello"})
```